# Getting the value of wildcard arm

Tags: wildcard, rust

How would I get the value of the wildcard arm in a `match` statement?

For example:

```
let a = 1i;
let b = 2i;
match a.cmp(&b) {
    Greater => println!("is greater"),
    _ => println!("is {}", _) // error: unexpected token: `_`
}
```

I'm hoping for something cleaner than storing the `enum` being matched in a variable:

```
let a = 1i;
let b = 2i;
let ord = a.cmp(&b);
match ord {
    Greater => println!("is greater"),
    _ => println!("is {}", ord)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
let a = 1i;
let b = 2i;
match a.cmp(&b) {
    Greater => println!("is greater"),
    e => println!("is {}", e)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know any identifier could be used as a wildcard.

Comment: Yes, but there's a catch to this: if you try to match on an `enum` variant that you didn't import with `use`, you may get [errors about unreachable patterns](http://is.gd/Dep83r). Here, `Greater` is imported automatically because it's part of the prelude.